# Footnotes in tabular environment

Tags: tables, footnotes

I am using a lot of tabulars in my dissertation, and I occasionally would like to append a footnote to an item in the table to explain exactly what I mean by it. When I run latex and convert into pdf, the footnote number shows in the table, but there is nothing at the bottom of the page. What can I do?

I am using MikTeX 2.9 and Winedt 10, and here is a (probably way to informative) MWE:

```
\documentclass[12]{report}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}

\usepackage{layout}
\setlength{\voffset}{-0.75in}
\setlength{\headsep}{5pt}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage [T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\usepackage{xyling}
\usepackage[super]{nth}
\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{cgloss4e}
\usepackage{abstract}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xr}
 \let\eachwordone\itshape

\addbibresource{ref2.bib}

\title{XXX}
\author{YYY}
\date{\today}


\begin{document}

blablabla. 

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1.5em}
\begin{table}[h!]
\caption{Z}
\begin{tabular}{c} \toprule Item\footnote{With this I mean...} \\ 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is not a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). Such a MWE has to have a complete document body from `\begin{document}` to `\end{document}` to be compilable. It should use only the package that are important to reproduce the problem to be minimal. It should be compilable or show only those errors which are part of the problem (but not errors, e.g., because of missing `\end{document}`).

Comment: Ok, I have now added \end{document}. As for reducing the packages, I have absolutely no clue which packages are relevant to this problem and which are not, that's why I have not removed them... And as for the previous threads on this problem, I have read them, but did not find anything that solved the problem for me. There was a suggestion to use `ctable', but I don't know what that means, it certainly not help to just say \start{ctable} instead of \start{table}. So, still noe clue...

Comment: The linked question has 8 answers with different solutions. Several of them with examples. So it should not be a problem to adapt one or several of them. There was not only the suggestion to use `ctable`! The MWE link in my comment leads to a page, where you are told how to reduce the number of packages. Believe me: You can do that! And the [Help Center](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help) [gives you answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates), [what to do, if you still have a problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions).